# How to plot column in unix in one line

Tags: unix, pipe, gnuplot

I would like to plot a column of data output by a script in unix in just one line. 
For example, something like

```
script | cut -f2 -d ',' | gnuplot ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `gnuplot` a plotting instruction in the command line, and can use the data piping special file `'-'`.

E.g.,

```
echo "1\n2\n4\n8\n16" | gnuplot -e "plot '-' u 0:1 w linespoints" -persist
```

The `-persist` option allows to keep the window open. If you want to produce a PDF rather, you can use:

```
echo "1\n2\n4\n8\n16" | gnuplot -e "set term pdf; set output 'plot.pdf'; plot '-' u 0:1 w linespoints"
```